# iOS4 (UIAlertView) why this code causes memory leaks?

Tags: iphone, memory, ios4, memory-leaks, uialertview

suppose you create a new iOS app from scratch, with just one single window.
then you put this code in the appDelegate application didFinishLaunching method :

```
UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
  initWithTitle:@"alert"                                   
  message:@"message"
  delegate:nil /* same problem with 'delegate:self' */
  cancelButtonTitle:nil 
  otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
[myAlert show];
[myAlert release];
```

build and run in simulator 4.1, attach instrument, and...
this causes each time a memory leak.
in simulator 3.1.2 on leopard, no problem at all.

Of course, in a real app, the UIalertView is trigerred by a button, but the result is identical.

What is the problem ?
is UIAlertView buggy until iOS4 ?

Comment: What makes you think it actually leaks? The memory will be in use until you close it, so make sure you test the right interval.

Comment: Leaks is more intelligent than that. It detects actual orphaned objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Don't check for leaks in a simulator**. It doesn't have the same memory model so reports leaks when there aren't any.

Test on a real device and if the leak is still there, report it as a bug to Apple :)

Comment: OK, thank you, dean, you're right ! If I test this code on real device, it doesn't cause leaks... but testing on device is so slow !!! And, curiously, on leopard / sdk3.1.2, the device and the simulator have clearly the same reactions to leaks.

Comment: Jesus, thx for this answer. I was going mad when checking leaks inside simulator :).