# What could be causing the memory leak in my iOS project? I failed to locate any dubious custom methods using Instruments

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, xcode-instruments

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705349/finding-the-line-of-memory-leak-in-instruments), locating the method causing memory leak is pretty simple with the help of Instruments.

But in my situation, the "extended detail" column doesn't show any of my custom methods, as shown below:
[image: Xcode screenshot]

How should I locate the leak point now?

Thanks,

snakeninny

Comment: Finding leaks is easy with Instruments. Finding what causes them is not. Try to determine when you would expect the object to be released, and which object is holding a reference to it, preventing that. Note that that is likely one of the objects in the list on the right.

Comment: Note, by the way, that the hexadecimal codes on the right are references to your code, but apparently Instruments has no access to your source code.

Comment: @fishinear any ideas on how to symbolicate the addresses on the right pane?

Answer (score 0):

The key is to launch Instruments via Xcode -> Product -> Profile. And then choose Leaks manually, you'll be able to see all the leaking symbols now.