# Leaks with UIAlertController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

I added `UIAlertController` in my app by creating a category on `UIViewController` with the following method:

```
- (void)showAlertViewWithTitle:(NSString *)title
                       message:(NSString *)message
                       actions:(NSArray *)alertActions
{
   UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title ? : @"" message:message preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

   if (alertActions.count) {
      for (UIAlertAction *action in alertActions) {
         [alertController addAction:action];
      }
   } else {
      UIAlertAction *action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
      [alertController addAction:action];
   }

   [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

At first, everything looks great but when I analyze leaks with Instruments, each time I call this method, some leaks appear:

[image]

Here is how the call of `showAlertViewWithTitle:message:actions:` is done

```
[self showAlertViewWithTitle:nil message:@"Test message" actions:nil];
```

Any idea why I get all these leaks?

-- EDIT --

I tried the following in a sample project:

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"message"
                                                   delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alertView show];
```

and I get the same leaks. I'm really not sure what's going on...

Comment: I don't see any leak using xcode 6.

Comment: What about Xcode 6.0.1?

Comment: I am using 6.0.1, how did you find the leak? I don't see leak panel in instruments

Comment: I saw a leak, sometimes it occurs.

Comment: @CarouselMin - I am referring the this leak option in Instruments: http://cl.ly/image/040c0N0V4029

Comment: Yes,I know,I tried that,it shows leaks once in a while, not reproducible every time I click the button to show the alert view.It shows a simple cycle of NSConstraints.

Comment: I'm curious if in your test, your program was consisted of 3 viewControllers. I think it's a bad idea to have the functionality as a category, especially since it can be one line to [[[alloc] init] show], at 16 bytes per allocation, stored as an array, and automatically de-referenced when the reference count will reach to 0. Have you considered your results from Leaks to be a false positive?

Comment: I also tried with a category, and I also get leaks

Comment: Hmm... strange. I have the same issue. I just created a new simple Single View Application just to test this. The leak happens sporadically. Any luck with as to know why yet?

Comment: It could be that the iOS library is responsible for the leak.  I got the same kind of leak when I used an actionSheet.  I chalked it up to how iOS 8 replaced uiAlertView and uiActionSheet with uiAlertController.  I think they must have messed something up in the internals of uiAlertController and caused a leak.

Comment: Has anyone filed a bug report with apple?

Comment: @dupuis2387 : I did on 09-Oct-2014, still waiting for an answer

Comment: any news on this? I am still getting this leak with xcode Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a)

Comment: @pasevin - No, I'm still waiting for an answer from Apple

Comment: Met the same problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4304131/44964

Comment: Are you running in Debug or Release?  I spent ages looking for the mother and father of all leaks last year - only to discover that the leak dried up for a release build.

Answer (score 3):

This is an iOS bug.

*This is also a duplicate of SO question [iOS 8 Only Memory Leak with UIAlertController or UIActionSheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26247221/ios-8-only-memory-leak-with-uialertcontroller-or-uiactionsheet/30312928#30312928) posted 1 day earlier.*

See [Apple Bug Reporter](https://bugreport.apple.com/problem/viewproblem) issue **21005708**, Memory leak in UIAlertController under ARC.

Answer (score -2):

The leak seems to be fixed with iOS 8.2 and Xcode 6.2

Comment: Won't leak on an actual device.